# XCTests and PHPhotoLibrary

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, xctestcase

I have functionality in the app that saved picture in photo gallery. An I wonder how to test this code:

```
func saveInPhotoGallery() {
    guard self.cameraOutput != nil else { return }
    if self.cameraOutput is UIImage {
        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
            PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: (self.cameraOutput as? UIImage)!)
        }, completionHandler: { (saved, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
               self.unsucessfullSavingOperation(error)
               return
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Let's assume now that I want to test in my case scenario that `self.cameraOutput` is and `UIImage` and sth went wrong and there is an error in `completionHandler` so I ended up in `self.unsucessfullSavingOperation(error)` method. This has separate tests of course, but what I want to cover is:

**Make sure whenever something will went wrong with inserting image in Camera Roll I will end up calling this method**

And when I try to call `saveInPhotoGallery()` in test target it produce Alert that this require access to your photo library (doh!). But there is a way to skip this alert in **Unit Tests** or check whanever it popup and press **allow**? (like I said, for this test, let's assume that I have this permissions)

Or there is a way to  mock this behaviour?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I'd mock PHPhotoLibrary. The main thing you'll need to replace is your use of `PHPhotoLibrary.shared()` which creates a dependency to a concrete instance. Instead, we can depend on an abstraction, that is, a protocol.

Then production code can supply `PHPhotoLibrary.shared()` as the instance to use. Test code can supply a mock object.

Let me know if you need more elaboration on breaking the dependency, or on making a mock object, or both.

Comment: Thanks, it's clear, but wonder if it's really worth to do this because mock object can return error, success, let's say I will test `self.unsucessfullSavingOperation(error)` and the same with success operation. There are still point of mocking since I test the funcs to handle all possible output separately?

Comment: So you already have unit tests for `unsucessfullSavingOperation`? In that case, mocking would let you handle those tests one step higher. This would bring `saveInPhotoGallery` under test, which would let you safely refactor it. It would also make `unsucessfullSavingOperation` a hidden implementation detail.

Comment: Would you also mock PHAssetChangeRequest in this scenario? I am trying to test a similar scenario but also trying to test that the assets localIdentifier has been returned using `var assetPlaceholder: PHObjectPlaceholder = assetChangeRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset` `let localID = assetPlaceholder.localIdentifier`

Comment: @EdwardFord It doesn't look like PHAssetChangeRequest makes it easy to get information out of it. Maybe see if a Test Spy will work. That's where you subclass the original class, but add ways to capture info that's hard to extract. A full mock might also work. I don't know which would be better — you'll have to try & see.